# Is there any way to export playlist from my music app to Spotify and play?

Tags: android, ios, spotify

I am working on a music application that needs to export playlist on https://www.spotify.com and play the songs. I have searched on https://www.spotify.com/us/ but did not get any way to do this. Can any one please suggest me way for doing this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where are you going to play the songs? You can use Spotify's Web API to [retrieve a user's playlists](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/get-list-users-playlists/).

Comment: I want to export my playlist from my app to Spotify and play in Spotify application installed in device.

Comment: What kind of application is it? Is it a web app using Spotify's Web API? Is the device a mobile?

Comment: Yes I am talking about mobile device. This app is to be developed on iPhone and Android both.

Answer (score 0):

Given the additional context provided by you in the question's comments, my recommendation is that you use our iPhone and Android SDKs. Using those, you'll be able to grab the signed-in user's playlists in order to get tracks, which you'll be able to stream, also using the SDK.

Documentation:

- [iPhone SDK](https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/spotify-ios-sdk/)
- [Android SDK](https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/spotify-android-sdk/)

Please note that the mobile SDKs are still in Beta, which means that they're not considered feature complete, and more importantly that breaking changes may still occur.